# Autohotkey `Send, ^c ` not working in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey

I am trying to simply get into the clipboard the selected text.
The code works fine with other applications (eg. Chrome) but not in Notepad++.
Reading some other related problems it seemed Autohotkey `Send, ^c` may be too fast for Notepad++. 
I have increased the delay for the query without success.

```
ClipSaved :=    ; Save the entire clipboard to a variable 
Clipboard =  ; Clear the clipboard
Sleep, 40
Send, ^c    
Sleep, 40

SendInput {LCtrl down}{c down}
Sleep 50    ; This way to send Ctrl+C thanks to Shadowpheonix
SendInput {c up}{LCtrl up}
ClipWait, 0.2   ;

if (Clipboard = "")
 {
    Clipboard := ClipSaved
} 
ClipSaved =   ;  Free the memory in case the clipboard was very large.

}
```

Configuration:
Windows 10 Home   Version 1903  OS build 18362.175
Notepad++ v7.8.6
Autohotkey Version 1.1.28.01

Comment: **`Send, ^c`** works here (Notepad++ v7.8.6, Autohotkey v1.1.30), even without the added SendInput commands (e.g. **`$F1:: Send ^c`**). In which context do you use the above code? Try it first of all in a standalone script (close all other scripts).

Comment: Thank you. Breaking it to small parts really helped. The code is run from another function in the script which run `Send, ^/` causing the selected text to be deselected (missed that part) in Notepad++ only (the strange part).

Comment: @BND so you could close this issue, right? even delete it